# Image upload validation with Yup and Formik with a separate component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, formik, yup

In my Nextjs app I'm trying to validate the upload of an image with Formik and Yup by passing a method `handleOnImageChange` in the component, but I don't know how to get it to work this way.. I also tried with `useFormikContext`, but without success. Can somebody help me?

```
 const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
        file: yup.mixed().required('Please upload an image')
    });

 function handleOnImageChange(event) {
      const file = event.currentTarget.files[0];
      uploadImage(file);
  }

<Formik
  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
  initialValues={defaultFormState}
  validationSchema={validationSchema}
>
  {() => (
    <>
    <div>
     <Uploader imageSrc={imageSrc} handleOnImageChange={handleOnImageChange} />
     <ErrorMessage
       name="file"
       component={InputError}
      />
    </div>
    </>
  )}
</Formik>
```

With the uploader component:

```
const Uploader = ({handleOnImageChange, imageSrc}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <input id="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif, .webp" name="file" type="file" onChange={handleOnImageChange} />
      {imageSrc && (
        <img src={imageSrc} width="200"/>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: You might want `useFormikContext`, https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormikContext , it can get the data from the Formik instance

Answer (score 1):

you have to set formik values for it to validate.
in the handleOnImageChange function you are calling upload image function which in my understanding is uploading image through an API endpoint and giving you a url in response.
make this function Async await the response then set formik state let me give you a sample code

```
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
        file: yup.mixed().required('Please upload an image')
    });

 function async handleOnImageChange(event,formik) {
      const file = event.currentTarget.files[0];
     let res = await uploadImage(file);
let url =res.data.url // depends on your API response
formik.setFieldValue("file",url)//"file indicates you state or formik value

  }

<Formik
  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
  initialValues={defaultFormState}
  validationSchema={validationSchema}
>
  {(formik) => (
    <>
    <div>
     <Uploader imageSrc={formik.values.file} handleOnImageChange={(e)=>handleOnImageChange(e,formik)} />
     <ErrorMessage
       name="file"
       component={InputError}
      />
    </div>
    </>
  )}
</Formik>
```

you will have to check for null or undefined incase the file is not selected by user and null object is returned when user opens file input and cancels selection of a file.